# Insert multiple rows at specific index while filling the rest with NaN

Tags: pandas

Let's say i have a dataframe

```
df = pd.Dataframe({'A': [6,5,9,6,2]})
```

I also have an array/series

```
ser = pd.Series([5,6,7])
```

How can i insert this series into the existing df as a new column, but start at the specific index, while "padding" missing indexes with nan (i think pandas does this automatically).

Ie. psuedo code:

```
insert ser into df at index 2 as column 'B'
```

Example output

```
   A   B
 ----------
1| 6 | Nan
2| 5 | 5
3| 9 | 6
4| 6 | 7
5| 2 | Nan
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the start index value is in *startInd* variable:

```
startInd = 2
```

use the following code:

```
df['B'] = pd.Series(data=ser.values, index=df.index[df.index >= startInd]
    .to_series().iloc[:ser.size])
```

Details:

- `df.index[df.index >= startInd]` - returns a fragment of *df.index*,
  starting from the "start value" (for now, up to the end).
- `.to_series()` - converts it to a *Series* (in order to by able to
  "slice" it using *iloc*, in a moment).
- `.iloc[:ser.size]` - takes as many values as needed.
- `index=...` - what we got in the previous step use as the index of the
  created *Series*.
- `pd.Series(data=ser.values, ...` - Create a *Series* - the source of
  data, which will be saved in a new column in *df* (in a moment).
- `df['B'] =` - Save the above data in a new column (only in rows with
  index values matching the above index, other rows will be set to *NaN*).

There is a subtle but unavoidable difference from your expected result:
As some values are *NaN*, the type of the new column is coerced to *float*.

So the result is:

```
   A    B
1  6  NaN
2  5  5.0
3  9  6.0
4  6  7.0
5  2  NaN
```